# Htaccess Apache Перенаправление

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, redirect

Хочу перенаправить те которые пытается открыть изображение прямо с URL-адреса на php страницу:

Пример: Этот линк

```
www.mydomain.com/images/test-image-1.jpg
```

надо перенаправить (redirect) на

```
www.mydomain.com/newpage/test-image-1.jpg
```

У меня уже есть примерный код но он не работает, где-то ошибся

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(adsBot-google|googlebot-mobile|googlebot|googlebot-image|msnbot|psbot|yahoo-mmcrawler|bingbot|bingpreview|Adidxbot|yandexbot|baiduspider) [NC]
RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+)/?  /newpage/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewrieRule /images/ /newpage/
```